# UILabel not updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry the basic question, but this bugs me for a while now.

I create a details view from a UITable and try to dynamically set its labels, but they are not updating:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  myObject *tmpObj = [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  myViewController *tmpVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIBfile" bundle:nil];

  [tmpVC.myLabel setText:tmpObj.myTitle];   // The debugger shows the text: myTitle = "myText"
  NSLog(@"%@", tmpVC.myLabel);              // NSLog SHOWS NULL

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:tmpVC animated:YES];
  [tmpObj release];
}
```

the connections in Interface Builder are set. The Connections Tab for File Owner shows

```
'myLabel' - 'Label (myLabel)'
```

any ideas why the value is not coming through?

A few more Observations:

- I also have an IBAction connected.
  This method is properly called when I
  click the connected button.
- I got a few pointers to my
  NSLog-statement, whether that should
  not better use tmpVC.myLabel.text,
  but trying also returns NULL.
- myLabel is declared as IBOutlet
  UILabel *myLabel in the interface.
  The property is defined as nonatomic,
  retain.

THERE'S THE LIGHT:

After playing around with it for a bit more I moved the pushViewController statement above the label updates. That resolved the label updates.

Working code looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 myObject *tmpObj = [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 myViewController *tmpVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIBfile" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:tmpVC animated:YES];

 [tmpVC.myLabel setText:tmpObj.myTitle];   // The debugger shows the text: myTitle = "myText"
 NSLog(@"%@", tmpVC.myLabel);              // NSLog SHOWS NULL

 [tmpObj release];
}
```

But I don't understand why I need to push my viewController first ???

Comment: do you release it anywhere in your code other than the dealloc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because the controller's view is lazily created only when accessed. Pushing the controller accesses the view.

Alternatively, if you add a line to access the view property, it will work too:

```
  myViewController *tmpVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIBfile" bundle:nil];
  tmpVC.view;   // Force view creation
  [tmpVC.myLabel setText:tmpObj.myTitle];   // The debugger shows the text: myTitle = "myText"
  NSLog(@"%@", tmpVC.myLabel);              // NSLog will display "myText"
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:tmpVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks @Hwee-Boon-Yar BTW, tmpVC.view returned a warning, [tmpVC view] works 100% for me ;)

Comment: I just found this with the same issue - this isn't a "thanks", just to point out the other option I used was to store the text in the view controller object, and set it in viewDidLoad

Comment: thanks for allowing me new thing to learn.Force view Creation.+1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

If `tmpVC.myLabel` is NULL, that probably indicates that you have not made the necessary connection in Interface Builder from the UILabel to your myLabel instance variable.

Comment: The connection exists: the file owner outlets shows 'my Label' - 'Label (myLabel)'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you `@synthesize` your `myLabel` property in `myViewController.m`?  You should be able to do something like:

`tmpVC.myLabel.text = tmpObj.myTitle;`

Comment: This was it in my case.  Forgot "@synthesize".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because your `NSLog` is trying to print out the actual label object.  Should you not have

```
NSLog(@"%@", tmpVC.myLabel.text);
```

In Response to the added information:  Your other issue would appear to be that you have linked an `NSString` to your label.  You have to link it to a `UILabel`.  So where you declare your `myLabel` var, change it to `UILabel *myLabel`, and the same for any matching property.

Comment: hmm, I think you're right there, but 
(a) when I try to add the ".text" I get a compiler error "member 'myLabel' not in structure or union"<br>
(b) the preceeding setText statement does not produce any updates in the view.<br>

Maybe (a) leads to the view not properly connected to the nib or controller, but can't see where the break could sit ....

Comment: added more to my answer, see above

Comment: Hi Codezy, sorry, that was a typo (corrected above). IB woudn't let me connect the 2 w/out a matching class. The Definition is UILabel ...

Comment: Are you releasing that label anywhere other than the dealloc, because that could do it.

Comment: Not a dealloc, but have a look at my updates in the question above (under THERE'S THE LIGHT). it seems the code sequence needed changing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this is what's going on:

When the view is pushed, the controller loads the view from the nib and hooks up the actions and outlets. Before this, the outlets are not connected, so tmpVC.myLabel is nil.

If you want to be sure, you could put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` of tmpVC to see when the view is loaded.