# Repaint UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**UPDATE:** As I'm not able to solve this issue, I've done a ugly workaround (added another label).

I'm currently trying to set the position of an UILabel within the following steps:

1) Update Text of the Label

```
lblFirstWheelDescription.text = @"Select the tooth shade";
```

2) Set new position for the UILabel

```
CGRect newframe = lblFirstWheelDescription.frame;
newframe.origin.y += 100;
lblFirstWheelDescription.frame = newframe;
```

Now what's confusing me. When the method is called the first time, nothing happends (UILabel doesn't move like set before). On the second call (same method), the initial y-value of lblFirstWheelDescription.frame hasn't been increased by 100. After the y-value is set another time while second method call, the label moves and y-value is increased.

I tried to force a repaint as follows - doesn't change anything:

```
[self.superview setNeedsLayout];
```

Does anybody know this behavior or knows whats wrong here ?

ihkawiss

Comment: Can you please tell me when you want to move your label and when your label is not moving?

Comment: TapGestureEvent action => Sets the new frame.
During or After this action, UILabel should move as set.

Comment: then what is the issue? Your method is not getting called when you tap or method is called but the label is not moving?

Comment: As I wrote above, method is called, new frame is set. But UILabel is repainted only after second call.

Comment: -(IBAction)moveLabel:(id)sender
    {
        CGRect newframe = lblFirstWheelDescription.frame;
    NSLog(@"be4 y=== %f",newframe.origin.y);
    newframe.origin.y += 100;
    newframe.size.width +=400;
    NSLog(@"y=== %f",newframe.origin.y);
    lblFirstWheelDescription.frame = newframe;
    
    lblFirstWheelDescription.text = @"Select the tooth shade";
} Try to call this when tap is called and let me know what happens

Comment: Already done, doesn't matter if I use CGRect or CGRectMake. Doens't update at all.

Comment: Ok.. if your label is moving with your code then i think the problem is with TapGestureEvent.

Comment: What should be the problem ? TapGestureEvent just calls a method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're assuming your function is being called when in fact it isn't? Try adding a logging statement `NSLog("TESTING");` to see when and how many times your function is being called.

Also, what is calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

you have to redraw the label. the viewwillappear call when viewcontroller redraw its view. You have to force redraw your label on the view.

Comment: Can you explain how you exactly would "force redraw your label on the view"?

Comment: you can redraw by notification. if your orientation changed then the whole view get redraw. you can call those methods force fully

Comment: i do not have any code. but you can also try this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720662/uilabel-not-updating?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed in the past that changing the properties of a CGRect doesn't make the UI element update:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,20)];
label.frame.size.width += 100; // does nothing
```

To make this work correctly, you need to create a new CGRect and assign it to the frame property instead of trying to modify the value of the existing frame object (which is what you original code is doing).

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20);
```

You can animate this change if you like using [UIView animateWithDuration:animations] easily enough, going from CGRect instance 1 to CGRect instance 2... you cannot just modify the properties of the existing frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the label according to your need but you have to redraw label in this loop  which you want to show from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884786/how-to-update-uilabel-programmatically-in-ios)

Check the Mert answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setNeedsDisplay from your view controller

```
[ViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

That will force your view and its subviews to update/repaint